# Laravel use singular table name for a model, how to use default plural?

Tags: laravel

The model Education in my project doesn't use Laravel default table naming as plural.

When i use `Education::all()` i give this error

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'ham_maindb.education' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `education` order by `created_at` desc)
```

I don't want to use `protected $table = 'educations';` Why default naming is not working and how to fix it?

Comment: You must define ```protected $table```. Laravel is a framework. Why use a framework?

Comment: Some table name is always `Singular`. Your table name should be `education`

Comment: The answer below does sum up the issue. Why don't you want to use `protected $table = 'educations';` considering your situation is one of the reasons the property exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel automatic plural form doesn't work for irregular nouns. So "education" will not be in plural form. Possible solution for this is only describing `$table` property

Answers in youtube: https://youtu.be/i0b2ejl7tXM